# Unable to resolve class : Gradle 'AppName' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem whit Android Studio. I did not pass this issue. :) I am waitin for this a week after. I delete studio and load agan bur why not woring. have I change to pc or home or country or world :)) Wyh it is not work>in...

1. I tried delete Android Studio from pc  a few times. :p
2. Clean project
3. Tried rebuild project
4. Invaidate caches/ restart
5. Synchronize project
6. Synchronize project whit gradle Files 
   7- I try to previous Android Studio ide's but not working!

Not wor KİNG :D

I cannot pass following issue on Android Studio:

> Gradle 'xName' project refresh failed
>
> Error:Cause: startup failed:
>
> initialization script
>   'C:\Users\Şerif\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle': 17: unable to
>   resolve class
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder  @
>   line 17, column 1.

error !  import

> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder    ^
>
> 1 error

**And How I setup new one Android Studio 
(I am usin android studio officail web site download. 
Is there any other action?**

please help :)

[image: error]

[image: build gradle app is not here!!]

Where is the build gradle app is not here!! There is somthing wrong in list
[image]

[image: this is another project but same issue]

Comment: `Failed to find Build tools`... You need to reinstall the SDK, not Android Studio

Comment: I tried to reinstall SDK and not working :(

Comment: I would suggest that you clear out the windows Temp folder

Comment: I tried reinstal SDK and reinstal Android Studio  agan bu not working :(

Comment: and I delete windows temp folder but not working again. is it about windows 10 or android studio or another things?

Comment: Works fine for me. I've seen some errors relating to usernames such as yours `Şerif`. Try making an account with "regular" letters

Comment: I change username form Şerif to serif bu not working :( I have to cahnege pc. ı will try another pc for work.  why android studio make this error. I did not change anything on my pc or studio what is wrong. I delete many times android studio for clean setup bu not working again.

Comment: The user folder name wont change even if you change username, create a project in a different folder and try it out.

Comment: Android Studio will be waiting for now. Because i can not solve it. I am now doing research for application development via Eclipse. Would you?

Comment: Eclipse would still use Gradle to build your project (hopefully). Gradle seems to be the problem, not Android Studio. Other than that, I use pure IntelliJ, not Android Studio, or Eclipse

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: can you resolved this issue ?? @ŞerifÇiçekdağ

Answer (score 0):

i got the right answer, after struggling for 2 days.
Go to file->project structure->project -> and there change gradle version to latest if you updated it.
In my case, i changed it from 3.3 to 4.0 yesterday and this error was gone.
Best of luck, if it will help you then accept my answer

Comment: There was a PC+JDK CONNECTION PROBLEM. reinstall JDK and connect pc and control it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :) 
There was a PC+JDK CONNECTION PROBLEM. reinstall JDK and connect pc and control it. now it is working well :) thanks for all answers